# Why does getting this error? TypeError: Object is not a valid argument for 'instanceof' (evaluating 'from instanceof Address - REACT-NATIVE

Tags: android, react-native, bitcore

Method of get UTXO

```
getUtoxs(address){    var options;
 if(Global.btc.network === "testnet"){
     options = {
         url: testnet.apiBaseUrl + "/api/addr/" + address + "/utxo"
 };   }else{
    options = {
        url: livenet.apiBaseUrl + "/addr/" + address + "/utxo"
  };
} 
   return  fetch(options.url)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) =>data)
    .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error);
    });  
}
```

Method of send btc

```
sendingBTC(utxos, tx) {
    try {
        var options;         

        var transaction = new bitcore.Transaction()
            .from(utxos)  //this line gets error
            .to(tx.to,tx.value*100000000)
            .change(tx.from)
            .sign(tx.password)
            .serialize();   
       /*.......................*/
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e); 
    }
}
```

this methods are getting an error. What is the wrong in this methods ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using bitcore-insight to make the getUtxos work.

The preferable way to do this would be to return a promise in the getUtxos() function which you can then consume, preferably using async-await in the sendingBtc() function.

Here's an excerpt of code to help you out.

```js
var bitcore = require('node_modules/bitcore-explorers/node_modules/bitcore-lib');
var Insight = require("node_modules/bitcore-explorers").Insight;
var insight = new Insight("testnet");

function getUtxos(address){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        insight.getUnspentUtxos(address, (err, utxos)=>{
            if(err) reject(err)
            else{
                resolve(utxos);
            }
        })
    })
}

async function sendingBtc() {
    console.log(req.body)
    let utxos = await getUtxos(address);
    // Another function to derive your private key 
    let privateKey = await generatePrivKey 
    bitcore.Transaction()
        .from(utxos)
        .to(req.body.txSendAddress,amount*100000000 - 3000)
        .change(changeAddress)
        .sign(privateKey);
    insight.broadcast(tx, (err, returnedTxId)=>{
        if(!err) console.log(returnedTxId)
    })
```

Hope this piece of code helps you out, remember you also need to derive your private key to sign the transaction and set up a change address (optional but recommended)!